# Remove $GNUPGHOME error during Dockerfile build

Tags: docker, dockerfile, gnupg

I build the rabbitMQ alpine docker image locally, see complete [Dockerfile](https://github.com/larrycai/rabbitmq/blob/master/3.6/alpine/Dockerfile)

```
RUN export GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)" \
    && gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys B42F6819007F00F88E364FD4036A9C25BF357DD4 \
    && gpg --batch --verify /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc /usr/local/bin/gosu \
    && rm -r "$GNUPGHOME" /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc
```

And randomly I got error below (mostly in jenkins CI system)

```
rm -rf /tmp/tmp.bBBnjn rabbitmq-server.tar.xz.asc
rm: can't remove '/tmp/tmp.bBBnjn/S.gpg-agent.extra': No such file or directory
```

or

```
rm -rf /tmp/tmp.GlfNBI rabbitmq-server.tar.xz.asc
rm: can't remove '/tmp/tmp.GlfNBI/S.gpg-agent.ssh': No such file or directory
```

It looks like the gpg agent is just stopped during rm.  (It exists when to delete, but disappear when delete happens)

I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS version

```
$ docker info
Containers: 2
 Running: 2
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 193
Server Version: 1.12.6
Storage Driver: overlay
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
..
```

Any solution for this ?

Comment: Any reason you not using the official `rabbitmq` image?

Comment: This is mostly for example purpose, and also we have slight small modification (alpine, multiple keyservers to avoid unstable network)

Comment: Post the actual `Dockerfile` if the one you posted is just for example. Else debugging it would be tough

Comment: Done and list my docker build env as well. It doesn't happen often

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change it to below and it should work all the time

```
export GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)"; \
        gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys "$GPG_KEY" || \
        gpg --keyserver keyserver.pgp.com --recv-keys "$GPG_KEY" || \
        gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$GPG_KEY" ; \
    gpg --batch --verify rabbitmq-server.tar.xz.asc rabbitmq-server.tar.xz; \
    pkill -9 gpg-agent; \
    pkill -9 dirmngr; \
    rm -rf "$GNUPGHOME";
```

`gpg-agent` and `dirmngr` run in background and at times takes time to exist. I believe `rm` picks up the files of these process and when it tries to delete the daemon and files area already gone. So adding these two pkill should remove the error

[image: HTOP]